# If int has a specific value, do something, if not, do something else

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, localhost

I'm trying to rank my users from 1 or 7. If the logged in user has Rank 7, say "you are staff". If not, do something else. But if I for example give user 1 rank 7, nothing happens. And then if I give user 2 rank 7, both gets the message saying you are staff.

I've been struggling with this for 3 days now without finding out the problem. What I want the website to do is to find out if the logged in user has rank 7 (Not if any others but only the logged in has rank 7), and if someone else on my database has rank 7 and not you, you're not supposed to get the "you are staff" message. I have a database called `GamesNet`, a table called `members`, and my user ids are called `memberID` and I have a couple of other columns called `username`, `password`, `email` and `Rank`.

That's an ok setup, right?
Here's my code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Rank, memberID from members where memberID');
$stmt->bindParam(7,$memberID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result['Rank'] == 7){
    echo "You are a staff member.";
}else{
    echo "Hello you are not a staff.";
}

?>
```

EDIT:

```
user.php: 

        <?php
        include('password.php');
        class User extends Password{

            private $_db;

            function __construct($db){
                parent::__construct();

                $this->_db = $db;
            }

            private function get_user_hash($username){

                try {
                    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
                    $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

                    return $stmt->fetch();

                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
                }
            }

            public function login($username,$password){

                $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

                if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];


                    return true;
                }
            }

            public function logout(){
                session_destroy();
            }

            public function is_logged_in(){
                if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }


        ?>

    Memberpage.php
        <?php require('includes/config.php'); 



        $memberID = user;
        $stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($result['rank'] == 7) {
                echo "You are a staff member.";
            } else {
                echo "Hello you are not a staff.";

//When i run this code, it tells me im not staff, even tho i am rank 7.
            }
        }




        //if not logged in redirect to login page
        if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 


        //define page title
        $title = 'Members Page';

        //include header template
        require('layout/header.php'); 
        ?>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

                        <h2>Member only page - Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>
               <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
                        <hr>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>



        <?php


/*
$stmt = $db->prepare('select Rank, memberID from members');
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($result['Rank'] == 7) {

        echo "You are a staff member."; 
       echo $result['Rank'];

    } else {
        echo "Hello you are not a staff.";
    }
}
*/
//When i run this code, it works. But it gives me the messages for all registrered users. 
    ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>Please Login</h2>
                <p><a href='./'>Back to home page</a></p>
                <hr>

                <?php
                //check for any errors
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                    //check the action
                    switch ($_GET['action']) {
                        case 'active':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'reset':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please check your inbox for a reset link.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'resetAccount':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
                            break;
                    }

                }


                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="3">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                         <a href='reset.php'>Forgot your Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>


<?php 
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: SO is a _terrible_ debugger. Have you tried to even log what you get and see if reality matches your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause in the select statement is missing a [parameter marker](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), e.g.

```
SELECT Rank, memberID from members where memberID = ?
```

and then [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) must use `1` not `7`, because it is the first and only parameter marker

```
$stmt->bindParam(1,$memberID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

---

You can also skip `bindParam` and pass the `memberId` as an array to [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$stmt->execute(array($memberId));
```

---

To process just one user

```
$memberID = 1234;
$stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members where memberid = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($memberID));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result['rank'] == 7) {
    echo "You are a staff member.";
} else {
    echo "Hello you are not a staff.";
}
```

---

To fetch all users

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members');
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($result['rank'] == 7) {
        echo "You are a staff member.";
    } else {
        echo "Hello you are not a staff.";
    }
}
```

---

You already have `$_SESSION['memberID']` in function `login`. So you could use it

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members where memberid = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['memberID']));
```

and have the needed data.

---

Better yet, you could extend function `get_user_hash` with

```
// user.php, function get_user_hash()
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, Rank FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
```

This would provide `rank` in one go, and avoid the additional database round trip. You could then save rank in function `login`

```
// user.php, function login()
// ...
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
$_SESSION['Rank'] = $row['Rank'];
```

Now you can just check for

```
// Memberpage.php
if ($_SESSION['Rank'] == 7) {
    echo "You are a staff member.";
} else {
    echo "Hello you are not a staff.";
}
```

without doing another SQL query.

Comment: Thanks! Dont know what happened with the comments, but when i change the rank and refresh the site, nothing happends, i have to log in and out to see the change, how can i make it change just from refreshing?

Comment: I guess, a moderator zapped the comments.

Comment: Okay, but i have still not figured out how to make it change just from refreshing the member page. Do you have any ideas on what i need to do?:)

Comment: No?:( Would really appreciate it sir

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't tell you more, than I already did. The check is based on the session variable `$_SESSION`/`$_SESSION['Rank']`. This variable is updated when you log out and log in again. To get the same result, you must update this variable in the script by setting it to the new value directly, or doing the SQL query to fetch the new value from the database.